# How do I change the Deskbar Applet panel icon?

Tags: gnome-panel, icons, applet

Is there any way, to change the Deskbar-applet-panel icon? I have checked in `/usr/share/deskbar-applet/art`, but none of those icons seem to change the panel icon or is there a different path for the icon(s) to be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check one of those:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/deskbar-applet.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/deskbar-applet.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/deskbar-applet.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/deskbar-applet.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/deskbar-applet.png
```

(Found those by running `sudo dpkg -L deskbar-applet`.)

Answer (score 1):

The deskbar applet icon is managed by your icon theme. If you change your icon theme, it will also change your applet icon. However if you just want to change that particular icon, you can modify the theme by doing:

`locate deskbar-applet.` - this will give you all locations of files with the name deskbar-applet, and now you can change the icon files under your themes' directory(ies).